# ray casting on earth's surface

Tags: point-in-polygon

Is it safe to use [ray casting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon#Ray_casting_algorithm) to check if a coordinate is inside a polygon specified as coordinates? Purpose of my question is because the longitudes are not parallel in a Cartesian sense, so is that a problem? If so, how big of a problem is it (for how big polygons it can matter for example), and how can I correct it? For example, can I map lat/lon to another domain and use ray casting safely?

I don't know much about GIS, but willing to learn anything related to my question.

Comment: Consider that spherical polygons are in one-to-one correspondence with their cones at the origin, which is are *polyhedra* in three dimensions. (Although such a polyhedron is infinite in extent, it could be capped by, say, intersecting it with a giant cube centered at the origin, making it a finite (compact) polyhedron.) Because raycasting works for polyhedra, then--if *correctly applied*--it must work for spherical polygons too.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is a little bit beyond my understanding (infinite/finite-compact polyhedron?) but it is good to know it should work. What do you mean by if correctly applied ? The very common implementation of the algorithm should be adapted or it is enough ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "very common implementation." Do you have a reference? Note that many textbook implementations do not correctly handle degenerate situations (*e.g.*, points on the boundary or rays parallel to an edge); this gets more complicated in 3D. BTW, the first two lines of the article at http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Polyhedron,_abstract explain (badly) what a compact polyhedron is. In plainer language, it is a polyhedron entirely contained within some sphere: it doesn't have any parts extending infinitely far from the origin.

Comment: Yes, sorry for ambiguity. This is what I mean by common implementation: http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html . Also I dont need an exact implementation, I mean edge cases can be handled anyway, just I dont want it to reach very wrong results for polyhedrons (I believe I meant polygon on sphere).

Comment: That page doesn't actually give an algorithm for polyhedra: it merely speculates that one can be developed. It's correct, but of course the devil is in the details. In your case, there are some subtle pitfalls. For instance, if your polygons were originally created in a projected coordinate system (they might have been traced on a map, for instance), then their edges are actually likely to be *curvilinear* and you are best off doing the point-in-polygon calculation in the original (2D) coordinate system.

Comment: I realized I asked it wrong, because I said like I want to make it run on sphere. Thanks for answering again. Yes, exactly the polygons will be traced on the map so they will have multiple lat,lon pairs; and I want to calculate if a given point(lat,lon) is inside this polygon. I really dont know about GIS, is the lat/lon system a projected coordinate system ? or in other word, for example, if I draw a polygon on maps.google.com, is it a projected coordinate system so I can assume it is 2D ?

Comment: Lat, lon is a "geographic" coordinate system: these two numbers identify points on a sphere and do not require any intermediate projection to do so. On *any* (flat) map, the coordinates are projected, including on Google.com. Both systems--geographic and projected--are 2D. The point I was making is that when you trace a line that's straight on the map, then in most maps it corresponds to a *curved* line on the earth's surface; and straight lines (geodesic segments) on the earth usually map to curved lines. This is an issue when mapping very large features using relatively few vertices.

Comment: So since it is projected to 2D, it is similar to polygon not polyhedron, as far as I understood, so I can think in 2D. If you say your answer not in comment, I can mark as answer, I think I cant do it for comments.

Comment: I don't think I've given an adequate answer, but I have achieved my initial aim of making the question clearer for anyone who would care to give a full response.

Comment: OK, thanks anyway. It was helpful discussion for me.